# .net core bad request for http GET and sending body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, get, httpclient

Im trying to send http GET request butIm getting 400 BadRequest.
I need just someone to confirm that I packed request properly.
I assume that my content is not good?

```
var um = "123456";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri($"{_iOptions.Server}{_iOptions.Method.GetData}")
};

request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"um\": " + um + " }"));
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

GetResponse response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<GetResponse>();

if (response.Code == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    response.Success = true;
    return response;
}
else
{
    response.Success = false;
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Bad Request means the content does not conform to what the API needs. Without knowing the details of your API we can only guess. My guess is that you are sending json as byte array content instead of string content.

Comment: I know @Crowcoder but I dont have any detailed specs for this api. I will try to send as stringContent and I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using HTTP (not HTTPS) you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to view the request.

Comment: are you sure it's `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"um\": " + um + " }")` and not `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"um\": \"" + um + "\" }")` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder -- Using `ByteArrayContent` is perfectly acceptable. I use it all the time for sending JSON. `StringContent` is actually derived from `ByteArrayContent`. Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/StringContent.cs).

Comment: @Andy good to know

Answer (score 0):

Because the data format is `application/json`, you have to use **HttpMethod.Post**. And the value should add **double quotes** in `(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"um\": \"" + um + "\" }")`.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var um = "123456";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:...")
        };

 request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"um\": \"" + um + "\" }"));
 request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

 var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
 responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 //...
```

In addition, ensure that the backend is received by object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult get([FromBody]MyModel myModel)
    {
        return Ok(myModel.um);
    }
```

And the model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string um { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Stefan0309, could you accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?